# Where can I find files stored on an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I recently took over some server infrastructure from a recently left server admin. I am a Rails dev, not a server admin per se.

I would like to find the files that were stored on the server and download them.

I have been given the private key, and was able to SSH into the main ubuntu EC2 instance.

I have no idea where to look.

How do I find a folder with all the files uploaded? They are largely images (jpg, gif, png) and documents (pdf, doc, xls, txt, etc.).

How can I easily find the directory where these things are stored, and how can I download them to my local machine?

I am hoping I can actually get access to the files like this. I saw the instance labeled "File Server (Production)" in the AWS web console.

We also have EBS volumes and snapshots...so if this doesn't work, then that is my next stop. But I figured I would at least work from here.

**Edit 1**

For what it's worth, it is an instance of Ubuntu .

**Edit 2**

I found the directory I want by doing `df -h`. It is in my `/var/www/files`. What I want to do now is zip up the entire folder and download it locally. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to login and search for some ruby or document files if you don't know where they are.

```
find / -name "*.rb"
```

Then you should get some ruby files with the path. Its possible that you get a lot of system files. You can change that pattern from `*.rb` to another one for example `*.doc` to find some docs.

Comment: I actually found them, by doing `df -h` and that gave me all the directories with sizeable filesizes. So now that I found the directory I am looking for....how do I zip it up and download it to my local machine? It is about 2GB+.

Comment: :) that another solution most times you have a separat partition.

Comment: Great solution!

Answer (score 1):

For Elastic Beanstalk (which still uses EC2 instace, but in "auto create mode"), the path to PHP app is `/var/app/current/`. This is on Amazon Linux AMI.

Comment: The question states - for the last year and a half - "For what it's worth, it is an instance of Ubuntu."

Comment: Yea, but that is not in the subject and a random user (like myself) could come to look for "Where can I find files stored on an EC2 instance?" question and find my answer usefull. You know, there could be many answers to a question and not all must be exact, but they could nevertheless be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Well am not a pro but

Option #1:

You could use rsync like this:

Code:

```
rsync --verbose -ae ssh  user@ipaddress:/path/to/remote/folder/ /path/to/local/folder/
```

The rsync command can be run on the local machine or the server (if it has   rsync).

Option #2(My preference):

Or you could tar the directory:

On the server:

Code(Run on Amazon Instance):

```
tar cf archive.tar /path/to/directory
```

On the local machine:

Code(Run on your machine hopefully it is on ubuntu):

```
scp user@ipaddress:/path/to/archive.tar /path/to/local/dir
tar xvf archive.tar
```

This seemed to work for my Ubuntu EC2